# How to re-render hyperHTML to the same element after content change

Tags: javascript, rendering, hyperhtml

I am trying to support the same type of thing as [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)

My code looks like

```
const elem = document.getElementById("profile")
const render = hyperHTML.bind(elem);
const name = elem.textContent
render`<b>Hi ${name}</b>`
```

So the API looks like

```
<div id="profile">alax</div>  <div id="profile"><b>Hi alax</b></div>
```

and I am using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to rerender on content change

**But** if the content is changed. hyperHTML says its rending to the right element.. but the element keeps its innerHtml(No update)

I can see the `<!--_hyper: -2001947635;-->` is removed then the content is set but setting up the **render** & **hyperHTML.bind** again does nothing

Any thoughts would be great! Thx

---

**Update**

The fix to the above problem is to call ``` hyperHTML.bind`` ``` then your normal render using hyperHTML will work

**Context** -
I am  using hyperHTML to create a custom element library([hyper-element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyper-element))

My use case: I work in a mix-tech project (some people use jQuery)

Side note, on the why. I want to support something like *partial templates*

Example of a partial template:

```
 <user-list data="[{name:'ann',url:''},{name:'bob',url:''}]">
     <div><a href="{#url}">{#name}</a></div>
 </user-list>
```

Output:

```
 <user-list data="[{name:'ann',url:''},{name:'bob',url:''}]">
     <div><a href="">ann</a></div>
     <div><a href="">bob</a></div>
 </user-list>
```

This is one use of setting custom content in an element you control

At the moment I have the setting of the content by 3-party working/re-rending

https://jsfiddle.net/k25e6ufv/16/

---

My problem is now: it is rending another custom element and getting the pass content to child element

It looks like hyperHTML is setting the child element's content in front to the element and creating the element without setting the content

Scroll down to bottom of source to see implementation!

https://jsfiddle.net/k25e6ufv/14/

Rending **crazy-cats**:

```
  Html`
  xxx: ${this.wrapedContent} zzzz
  `
```

Current output:

```
wrapedContent: ppp time:11:35:48 ~ crazy-cats: **Party 11:35:48** xxx: zzzz

<crazy-cats>Party 11:37:21 xxx: <!--_hyper: -362006176;--> zzzz </crazy-cats>
```

Desired output:

```
wrapedContent: ppp time:11:35:48 ~ crazy-cats: xxx: **Party 11:35:48** zzzz

<crazy-cats> xxx: Party 11:37:21 zzzz </crazy-cats>
```

Comment: it's very unclear what you are doing or what you are referring to when you say "content is changed" (which content?) and you use `innerHtml` which I am not sure what/why/where. If you could write a CodePen or a proper example (the simplest you can) I'd be happy to help.

Comment: P.S. if you change profile somewhere else without using the render you are bypassing hyperHTML. If you edit/update a content via hyperHTML be sure you *always* do that via hyperHTML. If you interfere with external, unknown, untracked mutations, for hyperHTML, you are doing something wrong. Remember, there's no virtual DOM in hyperHTML, the DOM itself you define is the structure you handle.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer as best as I can, but I'll start saying that when asking for help, it'd be much easier/better to show the simplest use case you are trying to solve.

There is a lot of "surrounding" code in your fiddles so that I'll try to answer only to `hyperHTML` related bits.

---

**hyper-element ?**

I am not sure what's the goal of the library but `hyperHTML` exposes `hyper.Component`, and there's also an official [HyperHTMLElement class](https://github.com/WebReflection/hyperHTML-Element) to extend, which does most of the things you manually implement in your examples.

I'll keep answering your questions but please consider trying, at least, the official alternative and maybe push some change there if needed.

---

**partial templates**

*hyperHTML* pattern and strength is the Template Literal standard. Accordingly, to generate TL from the DOM would require either parsing of the content or code evaluation. Both solutions aren't the way to go.

Custom Elements require JavaScript to work, and without JS your partial template is useless and also potentially confusing for the user/consumer.

You don't want to define what to do with the `data` in the layout, you want to define a Custom Element behavior within the class that defines it.

That means: get rid of old-style in-DOM output, and simply use the Custom Element class to define its content. You maintain the related class only instead of maintaining a layout that has no knowledge about how the CE should represent that data.

*TL;DR* the following is a bad hyperHTML pattern:

```
<user-list data="[{name:'ann',url:''},{name:'bob',url:''}]">
  <div><a href="{#url}">{#name}</a></div>
</user-list>
```

all you want to do is to write this:

```
<user-list data="[{name:'ann',url:''},{name:'bob',url:''}]"></user-list>
```

but **be careful**, the `data` attribute in `hyperHTML` is special only if passed through the template literal. If you want to pass JSON to the component, call the attribute differently.

```
// hyperHTML data is special, no need to use JSON
render`<c-e data=${{as: 'it is'}}></c-e>`
```

Above snippet is different from having JSON as data attribute text so your example should use `data-json` name, and the class should remember to `JSON.parse(this.dataset.json)` in its constructor (or have an attribute observer that does that for you)

---

**hyperHTML owns elements**

When you write:

> it looks like hyperHTML is setting the child element's content in front to the element and creating the element without setting the content

you are assuming you should care at all what `hyperHTML` does: you shouldn't.

The only thing you should understand is that `hyperHTML` owns the node it handles. If you trash those nodes via different libraries or manually, you are doing something wrong.

```
hyperHTML(document.body)`<p>hello ${'world'}</p>`;
// obtrusive libraries ... later on ...
document.body.textContent = 'bye bye';
// hyperHTML still owns the body content
hyperHTML(document.body)`<p>hello ${'world'}</p>`;
```

Above snippet is perfectly fine and totally wrong at the same time.
You don't update the `body` content manually, you don't interfere with its content via `jQuery` or other libraries, and you should never trash the content at all.

Once you chose `hyperHTML` to handle a bound context, that's it, you've made your choice.

This is true for pretty much every library on this world. If you use Angular to create something and you mess it all via jQuery, that breaks. If you write backbone templates and you mess later on with their content manually, that breaks.

If you bind an element to `hyperHTML` and you mess it up with other libraries, that breaks.

The only thing that won't break are wires, meaning the moment you create a wire, you can append it directly and that's actually a DOM node so it will be there, and it will be handled by `hyperHTML`.

Yet you should use `hyperHTML` to handle those changes, never jQuery or JS itself.

---

**The output is right**

When you say that the output should not contain the comment you are assuming you should care what output is produced via `hyperHTML`: you shouldn't!

`hyperHTML` uses comments as delimiters and these are absolutely fine for both performance, being unaffected by repaint and reflows, and for partial changes like the following one:

```
hyperHTML(document.body)`<p>${'a'} b ${'c'}</p>`
```

Both `a` and `c` will have a comment as anchor node to be able to update their content with anything later on.

```
hyperHTML(document.body)`<p>${[list, of, nodes]} b ${otherThing}</p>`
```

You change interpolations? All good, `hyperHTML` knows what to replace and where.

---

**force-own the content**

If you use a different template literal to re-populate a bound node you are trashing the cache and creating new content.

At that point you are better off with `innerHTML` because all the features of `hyperHTML` will be gone.

To start with, if your content can change so much, use an array.

```
hyper(document.body)`${['text']}`;
// you can clean up the text through empty array
hyper(document.body)`${[]}`;
// re-populate it with new content
hyper(document.body)`${['a', 'b', 'c']}`;
```

Above example is still better than changing template because all the optimizations for the content will be already there.

However, if you want to be sure the node the initial one created via `hyperHTML`, assuming no third parts script mutate/trash that node, you can use a wire.

```
const body = hyper()`<p>my ${'content'}</p>`;
document.body.textContent = '';
document.body.appendChild(body);
```

It's a bit extreme but at least faster.

---

**As Summary**

It looks like you are trying to sneak in `hyperHTML` into an application that trashes layout all the time through different third parts libraries.

Unless you create a closed Shadow DOM reference and you drop partial template through layout, you'll always have issues with libraries based on side effects with DOM content, libraries that mutates elements they don't own.

In `hyperHTML` the ownership concept is key, like in `React` you cannot change at runtime the defined JSX for the component, you should never try to change at runtime the defined template literal for `hyperHTML`.

Now, as much as I'd like to solve all your issues, I feel like it's right to ask you: are you sure `hyperHTML` is really the solution for your current app? It looks like surrounding side-effects caused by third parts libraries would constantly break your expectations if you don't use closed mode Shadow DOM and `hyperHTML` **only** to update your DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 1) The "partial templates" pattern is used alot in React. So I am just trying to do the same thing here. 2) Your example show simple elements("p" tag) but my point is hyperHTML breaks when trying to set the content inset a custom element. The custom web components(what ever it is) is not pass the content when created by hyperHTML. This is why the parent element (as defined in the Dom source works) and a similar element created by hyperHTML does not :(

Comment: I was using Shadow DOM before but it is not support in firefox

Comment: On "force-own the content" In my case 99% of the re-renders come from inside the element so the hyperHTML cache is good and on the 1% I dont mind rebuilding the element.. if thats the only option. But that comes back to the original question.

Comment: if you'll be able to show me the most basic example of what you are trying to do I might give you a better answer. Until that, I don't have much more to say except hyperHTML doesn't break, it's simply different from others so it does things differently. Nothing breaks, it has 100% code coverage because what it's meant to do, it does it properly. If you trash content via other libraries, then you are better off without hyperHTML. If you use hyperHTML to handle content, then it works. If it doesn't, please open a bug report in GitHub providing an example that breaks. Thanks.